# How do I solve a potential processing issue in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I try to do something simple like subtract two cells from each other, then drag the cells down to calculate all rows, and Excel just gives me one value for this action.

I made a video and posted it on youtube to show what I mean (just a minute long!):[Excel Issue](https://youtu.be/dMTsscLee80)

Is something wrong with my excel processor? It's for a fairly large dataset (10000).

Thank you for your advice

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It seems like you want to get your cells to be updated automatically. I've found a related question, that might help you [here].(https://superuser.com/questions/836324/cells-not-updating-automatically).

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure that you enabled the Automated Calculations in your Excel Spreadsheet, go see some of the sites here to enable it

[Run calculations if Workbook is in Mode Manual](https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-turn-calc-onturn-calc-off-in-excel/)
[Activate automatic calculations](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-in-excel-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Excel%20for%20the,This%20is%20the%20default%20setting.)

Answer (score 0):

From your video it seems you excel calculation option may be set to manual. Make it automatic. Please follow the below screenshot to change calculation option to automatic.

1. Go to `Formulas` tab.
2. Under `Calculation` section you will find `Calculation Options`.
3. From `Calculation Options` select `Automatic`.

[image]